# angularJs — inside the (Link) directive html working in a-href link and not working in button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

inside the (Link) directive html working in a-href link  and not working in button

Hi, 
i am created for common directives, here i need 3 types(link,button,icon) of commands,link directive its working fine but button not working

```js
 var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngSanitize']);
  app.directive('comonLink', ['$http', function($http) {
 
       return {
         restrict: 'AEC',
        require: '',
        scope: {
      setValues:'@',    
        },
        template:'<div  ng-bind-html="setValues" compile-template>   </div>',
   
  link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {
   var comonLink=iAttrs.comonLink;
    var splitValues=comonLink.split(",");
   
   if(splitValues[0]=='link'){
      scope.setValues='<a href="#/'+splitValues[1]+'">'+splitValues[2]+'</a>';
    }
   else if(splitValues[0]=='button'){  
     scope.setValues='<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block">'+splitValues[2]+'</button> ';
     }
   else if(splitValues[0]=='icon'){
    
    
    } }
      };
  }]);
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>testApp</title>
   <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
     <script data-require="angular.js@~1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
          <script data-require="angular-ui-select@*" data-semver="0.13.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.13.2/select.min.js"></script>
          <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
   </head>
          <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" data-ng-app="testApp"  > 
          <div class="wrapper"> 
             <span comon-Link="link,opRegistration,LinkName,isNew">  </span>  
 <span comon-Link="button,opRegistration,ButtonName,isNew">  </span>
             
            </div> 
          </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this filter to your app

```
 app.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
    return function (val) {
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
 });
```

and use it like this

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngSanitize']);
 app.directive('comonLink', ['$http', function($http) {
     ...
    template:'<div  ng-bind-html="setValues| unsafe" compile-template>   </div> <span> {{ setValues1 }}</span>',
    ...
   };
 }]);
```

Comment: It's really quite amazing that this isn't a built-in filter.